# How to lazy insert into a ExtJS 3 Store?

Tags: javascript, extjs, store

I try to insert a new record into a store to avoid `Ext.data.Store.load();` which will load all data again from a defined proxy.

Is it possible to insert a new `Ext.data.Record` without defining columns and datatypes?

I want something like this:

```
var myStore = this.grid.getStore();

myStore.insert({
  firstColumn: 'myValueForTheFirstColumn',
  secondColumn: 'myValueForTheSecondColumn'
});
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried [add](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-add) method?

Comment: Yepp, that worked thank you! ;-) I will post my answer in about 7 hours (because it's not possible for me to do that now because of stackoverflows reputation points)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Lolo,

this fixed my problem ;-)

Here's the code how I solved the issue:

```
var cm = this.grid.getColumnModel(); // getting the column model
var cc = cm.getColumnCount(); // getting number of counts (before add)
var lastStoreRecordIndex = this.grid.getStore().getCount() - 1; // getting the 
                                                                // last record
                                                                // (before add)
// the approximated ID which could be in the database
// (this is too optimistic in critical applications)
var approxId = this.grid.getStore().getAt(lastStoreRecordIndex).get('id') + 1;

// building a new record based on the columns of the current column model
var ch = '', data = new Object();
for (var i = 0; i < cc; ++i) {
  ch = cm.getColumnHeader(i);

  data[ch] = '';
}

this.grid.getStore().add([new Ext.data.Record(data)]); // add and be happy! ;-)
```

Answer (score 0):

After you update your store's records manually, you can also try and fire the store.reconfigure() method to force your grid to re-render.